# What is the difference between the `fun` and `function` keywords?

Tags: f#, ocaml

Sometimes I see code like

```
let (alt : recognizer -> recognizer -> recognizer) =
  fun a b p -> union  (a p) (b p)
```

Or like:

```
let hd = function
    Cons(x,xf) -> x
  | Nil -> raise Empty
```

What is the difference between `fun` and `function`?

Comment: Removed the 'fun' tag, since it has an established meaning other than your intent here.  I think the question will be better off without it, since some people filter it out using the ignore list.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The semantics for this is the same as in F# (probably because F# is based on OCaml):

- `function` allows the use of pattern matching (i.e. `|`), but consequently it can be passed only one argument.

  ```
  function p_1 -> exp_1 | … | p_n -> exp_n
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  fun exp -> match exp with p_1 -> exp_1 | … | p_n -> exp_n
  ```
- `fun` does not allow pattern matching, but can be passed multiple arguments, e.g.

  ```
  fun x y -> x + y
  ```

When either of the two forms can be used, `fun` is generally preferred due to its compactness.

See also [OCaml documentation on Functions](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but, describing 'fun' as preferred because it's more compact isn't the whole story, it isn't even a description of how to use it, and in no way are you comparing the two keywords! function is the same as saying, (fun x -> match x with ...), how is that more compact if you plan to pattern match?

Comment: `fun` also allows the use of pattern matching, but with only one alternative, like `let`

Answer (score 24):

The way I think about it

```
function patterns
```

is shorthand for

```
(fun x -> match x with patterns)
```

where 'patterns' is e.g.

```
| Some(x) -> yadda | None -> blah
```

(And

```
fun args -> expr
```

is how you define a lambda.)

Answer (score 8):

Russ Cam is correct in his answer.

Here is a posting on the OCaml list talking about it

http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/ocaml-beginners/2003/11/b8036b7a0c1d082111d7a83c8f6dbfbb.en.html

`function` only allows for one argument but allows for pattern matching, while `fun` is the more general and flexible way to define a function.

I generally use fun unless there is a good reason to use function.

You can see this in the code you posted where the `fun` declaration takes 3 arguments and the `function` declaration does pattern matching on it's input

Comment: couldn't you also do `let x y z = y + z`, with no `fun` or `function` at all?

Comment: @Rosarch, yes, of course. I think the question is implicitly about anonymous function definitions.

Comment: @NickHeiner @Rosarch Not quite, lambdas defined with `fun` are values, but a `let` isn't a value without an `in`

Answer (score 1):

```
fun x1 ... xn -> e
```

is an abbreviation for

```
function x1 -> ... -> function xn -> e
```